# Hard dependency issue between Newtonsoft.Json & Azure Functions V2

Tags: .net-core, json.net, azure-functions

Encountering below issue with  Azure Functions**V2** with **.net core**

*"Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 11.0.2) but version Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 was resolved"*

Tried out below but no luck:

- BindingRedirects not working with .net core
- Upgrading Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 to 1.0.30 leads to broken build in CI pipeline.

Why this hard dependency between Newtonsoft.Json & Azure Functions**V2**? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows and Microsoft isn't saying: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4049

The solution is to update to the latest version of the v2 [`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) SDK package which is 1.0.31 at the time of this writing. I don't know why you didn't just do this as part of troubleshooting.

Alternatively you can update to .NET Core 3 and Azure functions v3, i.e. any of the 3.x versions of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`.

Comment: As part of troubleshooting tried upgrading SDK package to 1.0.30 but it is breaking existing CI build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

newtonsoft json version is = not >=. This problem has been around for a long time, MS tracking this work here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/304

Create function v3 to avoid this error.

Comment: But issue isn't closed as per github url https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/304 ?

Comment: @prkat But you can use V3, it should be no problem.

Comment: I believe V3 works with core 3.0/VS 2019 which are not approved by our client. Currently we are using core 2.1/VS 2017. Any reason MS reason closed this ticket thought issue still persists  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/304? Confusing.